# Magento Admin display Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException): Please correct the target currency

Tags: magento2.3, php

After a lot of struggle , I could finally install Magento 2.3.5 p2 but now when I try to login to magento admin , it shows me the error message given below :
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException): Please[image] correct the target currency.

Please help me resolve this issue as I tried searching it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the target currency in the configuration. As you can change it from the admin configuration but your admin is not working.

You can change it from the database `core_config_data` table. Search for the currency in the table and assign a currency code in the value field to the result. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Thank You!